# How do I style Windows.Forms.Datagrid numbers to show like Excel?

Tags: c#, windows, user-interface

I want my datacolumns in my Windows.Forms.Datagrid to show like Excel, red for negative numbers in brackets, and black for positive numbers.

Also i want to right align the cells, but left align the header.  Is this possible?

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? ASP.NET? The answer depends entirely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work for alignment:

```
var cellStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle()
cellStyle.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight
dataGridColumn.DefaultCellStyle = cellStyle
```

For coloring you should probably handle some datagrid paint event and select different DataGridViewCellStyle for negative numbers.